# How to make the div wide enough when I scroll the screen?

Tags: css

How should I adjust the CSS for the `div class="breadcrumbs"`, if the table is wider than a screen and then background is not till the end.
[screenshot, where is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBZPj.png) I would like the dark blue bar to be till the end of the horizontal scroll (not just width of the screen).

Now it is like this:

```
div.breadcrumbs {
    background: var(--breadcrumbs-bg);
    padding: 10px 40px;
    border: none;
    color: var(--breadcrumbs-fg);
    text-align: left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is overflow the screen ..
try to make the table width to 100%

Add this inside the head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Your body:

```
<div class="myTable" style="overflow: scroll"> /** or hidden **/
   <table>
     ...
   </table>
</div>
```

hope it helped..

Comment: Thank you very much, it added a new scroll bar (so there are 2 a the same time now, but i does work)